# How do i avoid this improve this faulty path finding function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to write a path finding function to determine if a new region has been fully enclosed.    I have an object which contains a list objects that it is touching.  The goal is to see if we can find a path from the first object back to that same object.

The end result I need to get to is to determine if a new enclosed area was formed and also a list of the objects used to form that enclosed area.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTvyp.jpg

when adding a new wall it calls the checkForRegion function passing itself as the destination, current, and previous node.
It then evaluates every node it is connected to to determine if there is a path back to itself.  This works fine the first time there is an enclosed area is created, but after that it fails because there are loops in the path and it keeps rechecking following the path in a infinite loop.

```
   bool newRegionFormed = checkForRegion(this.gameObject,this.gameObject, this.gameObject);
```

```
  bool checkForRegion(GameObject DestinationObject, GameObject currentObject, GameObject previousObject)
    {
      
        WallDrawing currentWall = currentObject.GetComponent<WallDrawing>();
        //Is current object touching destination object
        //if it is and its not the first object coming from the destination as that is the start then return true
        foreach (GameObject nextObject in currentWall.currentCollisions)
        {
            if (nextObject != null)
            {
                if (nextObject.name.ToLower().Contains("border") && nextObject != previousObject)
                {
                    if (nextObject == DestinationObject && previousObject != DestinationObject)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    bool result = checkForRegion(DestinationObject, nextObject, currentObject);
                    if (result == true)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
      

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Look at A star pathfinding algorythm. What you want to do when checking a path is marking nodes you check as visited so you don't recheck to infinity. https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/07/25/a-search-pathfinding-algorithm-in-c/

Comment: Keep a list/Dictionary of objects or combinations of objects you already checked so you don't call the method again!